# How do I solve this unexpected token o in JSON at position 1?

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-redux

I set my jwt like this:

```
return fetch(`URL`, requestOptions)
  .then(handleResponse)
  .then((user) => {
    AsyncStorage.setItem("user", JSON.stringify(user));
    
    return user;
   });
```

And now I'm trying to retrieve it from AsyncStorage like this in my login reducer

```
let user = JSON.parse(AsyncStorage.getItem("user")
const initialState = user ? { loggedIn: true, user } : {};
```

But now I keep getting **Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token o in JSON at position 1
at Object.parse ()**. The error is coming from my login reducer. How can I solve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first parameters of function JSON.parse should be a String, and your data is a JavaScript object, so it will convert to a String [object object], you should use JSON.stringify before pass the data

```
let user = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(AsyncStorage.getItem("user")));
```

Answer (score 1):

`AsyncStorage.getItem` Returns a Promise object. So when you call `AsyncStorage.getItem("user")` it gives you a promise object, hence the error. Actually you should wait till the promise gets resolved. For more info about `AsyncStorage` please refer [this](https://reactnative.dev/docs/asyncstorage.html)

This can actually be achieved using below ways

- Using `await`

```
let user = await AsyncStorage.getItem("user");
```

- Using `Promise`

```
AsyncStorage.getItem("user").then(user => {
    //you can access user here
})
```

Hope this helps.